# Searching, inserting, outputing from binary search tree.

Tags: c, binary-search-tree

How can i do above things in one single programme with multiple duplicates keys and csv. type input data file?

Comment: @JoeWallis sorry, I wasn't paying enough attention to determining Code Reviews rules, thanks for pointing this out, removed my comment.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: assumed `KEY "," DATA "\n"` (no whitespace, for brevity) and appended a short sketch at the end such that the OP has a start.

I cannot repair it because I don't know the input but I can point out some of the errors you made. See comments in code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXNAMELENTH 64
#define MAXDATALENTH 1465

typedef struct node {
  char name[MAXNAMELENTH];
  char data[MAXDATALENTH];
  struct node *left;
  struct node *right;
} node;

node *root;
node *search(node ** tree, char *key, int count, FILE * fp_out);
node *insertion(node * r, char *key, char *value);
void deltree(node * tree);
char *strtok_r(char *str, const char *delim, char **nextp);


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  node *root;
  node *tmp;
  FILE *fp;
  FILE *outputfile;
  FILE *keyfile;
  FILE *fp_key;
  int i;
  int counter = 0;
  int bufsize = MAXDATALENTH + MAXNAMELENTH;
  int keyfilelen = MAXNAMELENTH;
  char *keyread;
  char *buffer, *saveptr;
  char *line = NULL;
  char *keyin = NULL;
  char *valuein = NULL;
  char inputkey[MAXNAMELENTH];
  char *target_key = NULL;
  char *keyline = NULL;

  root = NULL;

  /* Inserting nodes into tree */
  buffer = (char *) malloc(bufsize * sizeof(char));
  if (buffer == NULL) {
    // use the proper macros, please
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  // Check outputs! Always check outputs!
  // I just assume that it has not been done here for simplicity
  // and fear of posting-size limits (limit is 30k IIRC, that's a lot of code)
  fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
  outputfile = fopen("outputfile.txt", "a");

  // this is an infinite loop. How do you break out?
  while (1) {
    // fgets() returns NULL in case of EOF and error
    // (yes, both, so check, e.g.: with ferror())
    fgets(line, bufsize, fp);
    buffer = line;
    // I'm not fully sure, but I think you wanted a "=" instead of a ","
    // Please switch on warnings for your compiler
    keyin, strtok_r(buffer, ",", &saveptr);
    // NUL delimited? Really? Are you sure strtok_r() can handle it?
    valuein = strtok_r(NULL, "\0", &saveptr);
    // insertion() returns a node
    insertion(root, keyin, valuein);
  }


  /* Search node into tree */

  // Wrong type: keyfile is a filepointer (FILE *), not a string (char *)
  if (scanf("%s", keyfile) != EOF) {
    // hu? Please switch on warnings for your compiler
    keyfile = fopen(argv[4], "r");
    // where's keyfile? Gone?
    while ((fgets(keyline, keyfilelen, fp_key))) {
      keyread = strtok_r(keyline, "\n", &saveptr);
      search((&root), keyread, counter, outputfile);
    }
    // Please use braces, even here, thank you
    if (keyline) {
      free(keyline);
    }
    fclose(keyfile);
  }
  // This reads keys given as arguments at programstart, 
  // that's not what the teacher wanted
  for (i = 3; argv[i] != NULL; i++) {
    target_key = argv[i];
    search((&root), target_key, counter, outputfile);
  }

  // This program does not read from stdin.
  // Hint: stdin is also nothing more (although slightly less) than a file
  // but it is already open and you don't close it
  // (but it may not exist at all, so check first)

  /* Deleting all nodes of tree */
  deltree(root);

  fclose(fp);
  fclose(outputfile);
  return 0;
}

node *insertion(node * r, char *key, char *value)
{
  if (r == NULL)                // BST is not created created
  {
    r = (node *) malloc(sizeof(node));  // create a new node
    // insert data to new node
    strcpy(r->name, key);
    strcpy(r->data, value);
    // make left and right childs empty
    r->left = NULL;
    r->right = NULL;
  }
  // if the data is less than node value then we must put this in left sub-tree
  else if (strcmp(key, r->name) < 0) {
    r->left = insertion(r->left, key, value);
  }
  // else this will be in the right subtree
  else if (strcmp(key, r->name) > 0) {
    r->right = insertion(r->right, key, value);
  } else {
    if (strcmp(value, r->data) > 0) {
      r->left = insertion(r->left, key, value);
    } else if (strcmp(value, r->data) < 0) {
      r->right = insertion(r->right, key, value);
    }
    // what if both, name and data are equal?
  }
  // if you don't want to do anything with the returned
  // node than don't return it. Just an int indicating error
  // or something in the line
  return r;
}

void deltree(node * tree)
{
  if (tree) {
    deltree(tree->left);
    deltree(tree->right);
    free(tree);
  }
}

// searching does not compare the same way as inserting
node *search(node ** tree, char *key, int count, FILE * fp_out)
{
  if (!(*tree)) {
    return NULL;
  }
  if (strcmp(key, (*tree)->name) < 0) {
    search(&((*tree)->left), key, count, fp_out);
    count++;
  } else if (strcmp(key, (*tree)->name) > 0) {
    search(&((*tree)->right), key, count, fp_out);
    count++;
  } else if (strcmp(key, (*tree)->name) == 0) {
    // won't print anything, because you return before the printing
    return *tree;
    fprintf(fp_out, "%s --> %s\n", key, (*tree)->data);
  } else {
    fprintf(fp_out, "%s --> NOTFOUND", key);
  }
  printf("%s --> %s\n", key, count);
  // nothing to return here?
}
// Thank you for the proper reference!
// Seems to grow less and less usual these times.
/*
* public domain strtok_r() by Charlie Gordon
*
*   from comp.lang.c  9/14/2007
*
*      http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.c/msg/2ab1ecbb86646684
*
*     (Declaration that it's public domain):
*      http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.c/msg/7c7b39328fefab9c
*/

char *strtok_r(char *str, const char *delim, char **nextp)
{
  char *ret;
  if (str == NULL) {
    str = *nextp;
  }
  str += strspn(str, delim);
  if (*str == '\0') {
    return NULL;
  }
  ret = str;
  str += strcspn(str, delim);
  if (*str) {
    *str++ = '\0';
  }
  *nextp = str;
  return ret;
}
```

**EDIT**: the sketch. Please be aware that I didn't do *all* of your homework, I left a bit "for the student", as the saying goes.

```
/*
 * 
 * - Construct a binary search tree to store the information contained in the file specified
 * in the command line argument. Each record should be stored in a separate Node.
 * 
 * - Search the binary search tree for records, based on their keys. The keys are read in
 * from stdin, i.e. from the screen. 
 * 
 * For testing, it is often convenient to create a file of keys to be searched, one per line, and redirect the input from this file.
 * 
 * Use the UNIX operator < for redirecting input from a file.
 * 
 * - Examples of use: 
 * ./yelp1 datafile outputfile then type in keys;
 * or 
 * ./yelp1 datafile outputfile < keyfile
 * 
 * - Your program will look up each key and output the information (the data found) to the output
 * file specified by the second command line parameter.
 * 
 * If the key is not found in the tree,you must output the word NOTFOUND.
 * 
 * The number of key comparisons performed during both successful and unsuccessful lookups
 * have to be written to stdout.
 * 
 * - Remember that the entries in the file do not necessarily have unique keys.
 * Your search must locate all keys matching the search key, and output all the data found.
 */
/*
 * Tested with datafile produced by the following shellcode
 * 
 * # KEY "," DATA
 * counter=1;
 * while [ $counter -le 100 ];
 * do counter=$((counter + 1));
 * echo $(pwgen 10 1)","$(pwgen 10 1) >> testtree.db
 * done;
 * 
 * # ten random KEY
 * shuf -n10 testtree.db | sed -e 's/,[a-z]\+//g' > testtree10keys
 * 
 * # ten random DATA
 * shuf -n10 testtree.db | sed -e 's/[a-z]\+,//g' > testtree10datas
 * 
 * Please insert doublettes manually
 * 
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
// data produced has only 10 characters each (plus NUL)
#define MAXNAMELENTH 11
#define MAXDATALENTH 11

typedef struct node {
  char name[MAXNAMELENTH];
  char data[MAXDATALENTH];
  struct node *left;
  struct node *right;
} node;

node *root;
node *search(node ** tree, char *key, int *count, FILE * fp_out);
int insertion(node ** r, char *key, char *value);
void deltree(node * tree);
//char *strtok_r(char *str, const char *delim, char **nextp);
void bt_print(node * leaf);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  node *root;
  //  node *tmp;
  FILE *fp;
  FILE *outputfile;
  //  FILE *keyfile;
  //  FILE *fp_key;
  //  int i;
  int counter = 0;
  int bufsize = MAXDATALENTH + MAXNAMELENTH + 2;
  //  int keyfilelen = MAXNAMELENTH;
  //  char *keyread;
  char *buffer;
  //  char *saveptr;
  //  char *line = NULL;
  char *keyin = NULL;
  char *valuein = NULL;
  //  char inputkey[MAXNAMELENTH];
  //  char *target_key = NULL;
  //  char *keyline = NULL;

  char *e;
  int res;
  char *comma;


  root = NULL;

  // must have at least one argument
  if (argc < 2) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s datafile [< key-list]\n", argv[0]);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  /* Inserting nodes into tree */
  buffer = malloc(bufsize);
  if (buffer == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Malloc failed\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
  if (fp == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Opening \"%s\" for reading failed\n", argv[1]);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  outputfile = fopen("outputfile.txt", "a");
  if (fp == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Opening \"outputfile.txt\" for appending failed\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  while ((e = fgets(buffer, bufsize, fp))) {
    if (e == NULL) {
      if (ferror(fp)) {
        // TODO: check errno for the exact kind of error
        fprintf(stderr, "An eror occured during reading \"%s\"\n", argv[1]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      } else if (feof(fp)) {
        break;
      }
    }
    // assuming strict KEY","DATA"\n" and without whitespace
    // otherwise you need to check every step here!
    // valuein points to the comma before DATA
    valuein = strchr(buffer, ',');
    // valuein points to DATA
    valuein++;
    // DATA is 10 characters large
    valuein[10] = '\0';
    // comma points to the comma before DATA
    comma = strchr(buffer, ',');
    // make *comma NUL
    *comma = '\0';
    keyin = buffer;
    // ignoring return for now
    //printf("%s,%s\n",keyin, valuein);
    (void) insertion(&root, keyin, valuein);
  }

  bt_print(root);

  // search-keys come from either stdin or get typed in.
  // things typed in are also stdin
  while ((res = scanf("%10s", buffer)) == 1) {
    //printf("%s\n",buffer);
    search(&root, buffer, &counter, outputfile);
    printf("Misses for KEY \"%s\" = %d\n", buffer, counter);
    counter = 0;
  }

  /* Deleting all nodes of tree */
  deltree(root);

  fclose(fp);
  fclose(outputfile);
  return 0;
}

void bt_print(node * leaf)
{
  if (leaf) {
    printf("%s,%s\n", leaf->name, leaf->data);
    bt_print(leaf->left);
    bt_print(leaf->right);
  }
}

int insertion(node ** r, char *key, char *value)
{
  if (*r == NULL) {
    *r = malloc(sizeof(node));
    if (r == NULL) {
      return 0;
    }
    strcpy((*r)->name, key);
    strcpy((*r)->data, value);

    (*r)->left = NULL;
    (*r)->right = NULL;
  }
  // Checks for returns omitted for clarity
  else if (strcmp(key, (*r)->name) < 0) {
    insertion(&(*r)->left, key, value);
  }
  // else this will be in the right subtree
  else if (strcmp(key, (*r)->name) > 0) {
    insertion(&(*r)->right, key, value);
  } else {
    if (strcmp(value, (*r)->data) > 0) {
      insertion(&(*r)->left, key, value);
    } else if (strcmp(value, (*r)->data) < 0) {
      insertion(&(*r)->right, key, value);
    }
    // what if both, name *and* data are equal?
    return 0;
  }

  return 1;
}

void deltree(node * tree)
{
  if (tree) {
    deltree(tree->left);
    deltree(tree->right);
    free(tree);
  }
}

// search still cannot find multiple occurences of KEY
// Can you repair it?
node *search(node ** tree, char *key, int *count, FILE * fp_out)
{
  node *tmp;
  if (!(*tree)) {
    printf("%s --> NOTFOUND\n", key);
    fprintf(fp_out, "%s --> NOTFOUND", key);
    return NULL;
  } else {
    if (strcmp(key, (*tree)->name) < 0) {
      tmp = search(&((*tree)->left), key, count, fp_out);
      (*count)++;
      return tmp;
    } else if (strcmp(key, (*tree)->name) > 0) {
      tmp = search(&((*tree)->right), key, count, fp_out);
      (*count)++;
      return tmp;
    } else {
      // HINT 1: check  (*tree)->left->name and (*tree)->right->name
      //       (recursively) and print it as long as key==name
      // HINT 2: you don't need recursion, you can do it in a loop
      printf("FOUND KEY %s --> DATA %s\n", key, (*tree)->data);
      fprintf(fp_out, "%s --> %s\n", key, (*tree)->data);
      return *tree;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi there, the input file is a csv file.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have one quick question. My Key and Data have much longer length than 10, and the lengths of them are uncertain. Shall I use a for loop to extract every key and data? Cheers

Comment: @Dekko.Delanforrings Yes. The simplest way (for me, YMMV, of course) would be to use `fgetc()` to fill a buffer until you get to the delimiter between KEY and DATA (that's your key) and go on until the newline character(s), filling another buffer with DATA. You can also read the file line-wise with `getline()` (not C but somewhere in the Doc here is a working implementation), replace the delimiter and newline with `\0` and use two pointers to point to the start of KEY and DATA respectively. this enables you to use `strcpy()` to fill the tree-node.

Comment: hi, may i ask what bt_print(node *leaf) does?

Comment: @Dekko.Delanforrings it prints the tree. Postorder. You can also have preorder and inorder. See e.g.:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal.

Comment: i am not very sure why you put it as int *count btw. Could you please explain to me as well? thank you very much

Comment: Hi, i was trying to compile and run my code. I get no output at all.

Comment: hi, i think something wrong with the while loop which shall read the input. I cant read any input

Comment: Your new code (looks familiar to me...mmh... ;-) ) does not compile. Switch on **all** warnings your compiler has and get rid of **all** of them. Most of it is probably just C&P failure (some semicolons are missing, curious characters, missing quote in `printf` in `search` and so on) but a lot of it is not. Use `getline()` (http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c/507/files-and-i-o-streams/8274/get-lines-from-a-file-using-getline) to fill the buffer. Don't forget to check the length!. The trick with `point` does not work, set `valuein` directly instead.

Comment: it can be compiled actually without any warning . do you mean i shall use getline() to fill the buffer? is getline() in C library?

Comment: getline() u mentioned shall I use for valuein and keyin or the stdin? Thank you

Comment: @Dekko.Delanforrings if it compiles at your place, please check what you posted, it must be different from what you have at hand. Use `getline()` to read the data-file in; you can leave the `scanf()` method for stdin as it is, but you should add a field-width to it. PS: are you sure you switched the warnings on? All of them?

Comment: yes, there is no warning at all. I will update my code here soon. Also, I find either insertion or search function has some issues which lead to no result of output.

Comment: for latest code please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39305832/why-does-my-code-read-nothing-from-input